# jQuery last element

Tags: jquery

```
    $(':input').blur(function () {
            $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px #ccc');
            // Check if last input and do line below
            //if(condition if $(this) is last element)
            //   $('#someOtherId').focus();
        });
```

In the code above, how to know id $(this) is last input of all selected input?

Comment: Is it possible to do [-1] or am I thinking of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(':input').blur(function() {
    if ($('input:last').is(this)) {
        // do something with last
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px #ccc');
});
```

#### [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/eYZU5/9/)

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but wouldn't that always be true since `$(this)` matches a single element in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Try like below,

```
var $input = $(':input');
$input.blur(function () {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px #ccc');
    // Check if last input and do line below
    if ($input.index(this) == $input.length - 1) {
         //$('#someOtherId').focus();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/eYZU5/3/

Comment: This is the most efficient of the answers if you're going 100% client side.  The ones using `:last` (including mine) don't seem to work as far as I can tell on jsfiddle.  Another alternative is to just give the last element a certain id on the server side and check for that.

Comment: I can break it though: http://jsfiddle.net/eYZU5/1/ try adding a selector to `.index()` http://jsfiddle.net/eYZU5/2/

Comment: @KevinB Oh nice.. thanks though.. See updated patch :) **Edit:** I just did `$input.index(this)` added context so it would get `index` in `$input`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "all selected input", but you can do a quick check by using `.is()` and the `:last` selector.

```
$(':input').blur(function () {

    var _this = $(this);

    if (_this.is(':last')) {
        // do something
    }

});
```

You might also want to look at `:last-child`, if that fits your requirements better.